# Convert Word file To PDF through Word Automation service using CSOM

Tags: csom, word-automation

I have to to convert Word file to PDF using WAS with Csom but  on Microsoft.Office.Word.Server.Conversions.syncConverter method give exception of Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server. while Assembly is Added and file is fine. Below is my Code

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(FileInfo.Stream))
{
    using (MemoryStream pdfContents = new MemoryStream())
    {
        //var proxy = clientContext.Web.Context.ApplicationName..Proxies.Where(p => p is WordServiceApplicationProxy).FirstOrDefault();
        //if (proxy == null)
        //  return null;
        // Initialise Word Automation Service
        SyncConverter sc = new SyncConverter("Word Automation Service Application");
        //sc.UserToken = ;
        sc.Settings.UpdateFields = true;
        sc.Settings.OutputFormat = SaveFormat.PDF;
        // Convert to PDF
        ConversionItemInfo info = sc.Convert(sr.ToString(), pdfContents.ToString());
        if (info.Succeeded)
        {
            var fileStream = new FileStream((string)sourceFile.ServerRelativeUrl, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            pdfContents.WriteTo(fileStream);
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WAS cannot be used with CSOM. The class you're referencing is the Server Side Object Model (SSOM). This means that you need to deploy a Full Trust Solution using SSOM.